# Convert a Rails Gem / Engine to an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

The rails engines feature is pretty good, and I have watched the Railcasts and read the Rails documentation on it. I can see how you can access or override all the relevant components in the engine.

However, say I wanted to drastically modify the engine's code, is it possible to convert the engine back into a normal Rails app, and then take it from there. Is there anything else involved other than copying the directories in the gem over an empty application directory?

I am looking at this engine:

https://github.com/ging/social_stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can, just go to https://github.com/rails/rails & hit the fork button to fork the repository to your github account (assuming you already have one setup). Afterwards, clone the forked project to your local machine with:

```
git clone your_forked_repository_url.git
```

If you don't feel the need to fork your own version run:

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
```

At this point you can make modifications to your heart's content. To use a local copy of the gem in a rails application add the following to your Gemfile (replacing the old rails gem):

```
gem "rails", :path => "/somewhere/your_rails_project"
```

All of this and more is highlighted in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: The forked custom version described here is probably the best way to go. It will potentially allow you to take advantage of advancements to the original source, as well as speed up the test suite of your app. That being said, you can basically just copy the gem files into a new blank app, and go from there, if you're not concerned about the advantages of keeping it gemified. Also, it may be worth looking into whether any of the changes you want to implement would be accepted back into the original source...